# $x$ for which the mean of the random variable $Z=X|X+Y=n$ is $n/2$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution

The problem is: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Poisson random variables $X\in Po(x+6)$ and $Y\in Po(x^2+6x-20)$. Find that $x$ for which the mean of the random variable $Z=X|X+Y=n$ is $n/2$.

I'm not sure if the condition is only $X$ or it's $(X+Y)$ because there is no brackets and if they mean that $X+Y=n$. I've tried to search for some similar problem but can't find anything.

If someone has an idea how to approach this I'll be very thankful!

Comment: You may try to compute the conditional pmf of $X | X + Y = n$ in general parameters. This is a well-known distribution and you can write the mean immediately. On the other hand note that $E[X | X + Y = n] = E[Y | X + Y = n] = n/2$ and intuitively their parameters should looks the same.

Comment: @BGM Thanks a lot! I havn't noticed that it will give us a binomial distribution and from there it is easy. I think that I got the answer :) Thank you again!